# Misleading description concerning the 'final' Keyword in the C++11 standard?

Tags: c++11

```
class A
{
    virtual void foo();
}

class B : public A
{
    void foo() final;
}
```

Quote from C++11 standard § 9.2/8:

> A *virt-specifier-seq* shall contain at most one of each *virt-specifier*. A *virt-specifier-seq* shall appear only in the declaration of a virtual member function (10.3)

A *virt-specifier* includes `final` and `override`.

Function `foo` in class `B` is a derived virtual member function (even not declared as `virtual` in `B`). This is legal according to the above quote from the C++11 standard.

But what is with the following case:

```
class C
{
    virtual void bar() final;
}
```

According to the C++11 standard class `C` should compile, though the `virtual` and `final` keywords are contrary.

Therefore the C++11 standard $9.2/8 confused me a little bit. It's not precise enough. I don't even know if this really compiles, and if its behaviour is well defined.

Comment: That's not only legal, it's even useful (to maintain layout compatibility of the v-table, on platforms which provide platform-specific guarantees about v-table layout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"though the `virtual` and `final` keywords are contrary". No. The statement you have quoted says only that you cannot use multiple `override` or multiple `final` keywords in the same declaration. `virtual` itself is optional and redundant if any of them are given. The `virtual` keyword in C as well as in B is optional, because the base class already declares that method virtual. A `final` method is always virtual, too. It is not useful (and probably illegal - but not sure about the standard) to use `final` on something that is not an overridden method from the base class.

In previous versions of the C++ standard, `final` and `override` did not exist, so it was customary to declare overrides virtual for readability. Now you have `override`, which not only makes it obvious that this is an override, but also generates a compiler error if it is not (e.g. because the method name in the overriding class has a typo). For backward compatibility, declaring `virtual` *and* `override` was kept legal.

Comment: `s/i.e. because/e.g. because/`, since a typo in name is not the only reason for the error to happen: wrong signature will also generate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
virtual void bar() final;
                   ^^^^^
```

That is the *virt-specifier-seq*.  It contains `final`, which is a *virt-specifier*, and there is one of them.

This is perfectly legal.  As is this:

```
virtual void bar() final override;
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is in the declaration of a virtual member function, and contains at most one of each *virt-specifier*.

What is illegal is

```
virtual void bar() final final;
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

here, it contains two `final`, which violates the rule "at most one of each *virt-specifier*".